# My home page automatically redirects to the user page

Tags: wordpress

I installed the Ultimate Member plugin in my wordpress site and I created all the needed pages (register, login...). On my side, it seems to work fine, but one of the site's users is redirected to his profil when he try to access the home page. However, the home page is not linked to any UM behaviour.

We tried to clear cookies and cache but nothing changes, and I don't see where the problem can come from.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have to set the Default Start Site in the Customizer, maybe this helps with your problem. Otherwise please check if the Link in your Menu is correct and refers to your Homepage.[Customizer Start Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG1VL.png)

Comment: Where do you find this settings ? The link in the menu is correct.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, please go to the Customizer and then to Startsite Settings!

Comment: the home page is selected, the problem doesn't seem to come from here.